# Unable to open app from unidentified developer

Tags: macos, install

I'm trying to install [VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/) on my MacBook. My operating system is macOS Mojave 10.14.5. When I try to install the software, I receive the following unidentified developer message:

[image]

But when I go to the System Preferences, I can't find any options to overrule it.

[image]

I was wondering why is this the case and how to fix it.